# I have to use a while loop to convert decimal into binary in Java

Tags: java

I have to manually convert decimal numbers into binary, but have to output from the range of 1-256 (so no user input). I believe I just take the variable for incrementing the decimal up to 256 and using that as the input for the binary conversion, but I keep getting an infinite loop. I am not allowed to use the binary conversion function so I have to convert manually.

```
int decimal;
for (decimal = 1; decimal <= 256; decimal++) //this is how i get from 1-256

//this is the binary where i keep getting the infinite loop
int binaryNumber = 0;
        while (decimal > 0) {
            decimal = decimal / 2;
            binaryNumber = (decimal % 2) + binaryNumber;
            }
        System.out.println(binaryNumber);
```

what am I doing wrong, thanks?

Comment: this is not even compiling isn't

Comment: If you keep dividing `decimal` by 2, it will *never* reach `256` so your outer loop won't terminate. Solution: copy `decimal` to a temporary variable in the outer loop and use the temporary variable in the inner loop.

Comment: Assuming you forgot some braces etc. I guess the code below the for-loop is all part of the body. If it is then you shouldn't decrement `decimal` until it is 0 _inside_ the loop that should loop until it is > 256.

Comment: I only added what was necessary to the question, I could post the whole thing? And on my console it just keeps printing 1s and 0s until I stop it.

Comment: Besides that, why not `Integer.toBinaryString(decimal)` and be done?

Comment: Because I am not allowed to use it for my assignment.

Comment: You might want to try stepping through your code with a debugger and watch the values, especially that of `decimal`. That should help you understand the problem with your code (if our comments didn't already).

Comment: @Thomas because it's home work.

Comment: @deyizzle. see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
public class Class {
  private static String intToBinary(final int input, final int count) {
    int powerOf2 = (int) Math.pow(2, count);
    if (count < 0) {
      return "";
    } else if (input < powerOf2) {
      return "0" + intToBinary(input, count - 1);
    } else {
      return "1" + intToBinary(input - powerOf2, count - 1);
    }
  }

  public static String intToBinary(final int input) {
    return intToBinary(input, (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(input) / Math.log(2)));
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(intToBinary(7));
    System.out.println(intToBinary(8));
    System.out.println(intToBinary(100));
    System.out.println(intToBinary(1234567890));
  }
}
```

Here is the same algorithm in a while loop:

```
public class Class {
  public static String intToBinary(final int input) {
    int count = (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(input) / Math.log(2));
    int remaining = input;
    final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    while (count >= 0) {
      final int powerOf2 = (int) Math.pow(2, count);
      if (remaining < powerOf2) {
        output.append("0");
      } else {
        output.append("1");
        remaining -= powerOf2;
      }
      count--;
    }
    return output.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(intToBinary(7));
    System.out.println(intToBinary(8));
    System.out.println(intToBinary(100));
    System.out.println(intToBinary(1234567890));
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to use a while loop for the conversion unfortunately, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in each iteration of the for loop you set decimal to 0. Change the for loop to use a different value, like i, then assign `decimal = i`.

Comment: what would i initialize i as?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args)   {

int [] nums = new int [256];

for (int i =0; i< nums.length;i++)
     {

       nums[i] = i+1;
     }

for (int i =0; i< nums.length;i++)
     {

        System.out.println(decimalTobinary(nums[i]));
     }


}

public static String decimalTobinary(int num){
 int binary[] = new int[9];
 int index = 0;
 while(num > 0)
      {
        binary[index++] = num%2;
        num = num/2;
      }

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for(int i = index-1;i >= 0;i--)
      {
            sb.append(binary[i]);
      }
       return sb.toString();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer on stackoverflow

```
    while(binary_number!=0)
    {
        int digit = binary_number % 10; //take out the digits from the end
        
        decimal = decimal + digit*(Math.pow(2, i)); // use a accumulator to add up the digits while multiplying it with the correct power of 2 
        
        i++; // use a counter for using for the correct value to raise the power of 2 to.
        
        binary_number = binary_number/10; // divide the number by ten so that the last digit used in calculation is no more used 
    }
     System.out.println(decimal);
```